# Why a c++ string tokenizer isn't working

Tags: c++, string, tokenize

I tried to write a simple std::string tokenizer in c++, and I can't get it to work quite right.  I found one online which *does* work, and I understand why it works.... but I still can't figure out why my original one *isn't* working.  I'm assuming its some stupid little thing that I'm missing.... I'd appreciate a pointer in the right direction; thanks!

input (random character and symbols with "\n" "\t"):

```
"This is a test string;23248h> w chars, aNn, 8132; ai3v2< 8&G,\nnewline7iuf32\t2f,f3rgb, 43q\nefhfh\nu2hef, wew; wg"
```

tokenizer:

```
size_t loc, prevLoc = 0;
while( (int)(loc = theStr.find_first_of("\n", prevLoc) ) > 0) {
    string subStr = theStr.substr(prevLoc, loc-1);        // -1 to skip the \n
    cout << "SUBSTR: '" << subStr << "'" << endl << endl;
    tokenizedStr->push_back( subStr );
    prevLoc = loc+1;
} // while
```

output:

```
SUBSTR: 'This is a test string;23248h> w chars, aNn, 8132; ai3v2< 8&G'

SUBSTR: 'newline7iuf32  2f,f3rgb, 43q
efhfh
u2hef, wew; wg'

SUBSTR: 'efhfh
u2hef, wew; wg'
```

Notice that the second "SUBSTR" (apparently) still has the newline characters ("\n") in it

Compilable code:

```
#include <vector.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    string testStr = "This is a test string;23248h> w chars, aNn, 8132; ai3v2< 8&G,\nnewline7iuf32\t2f,f3rgb, 43q\nefhfh\nu2hef, wew; wg";
    vector<string> tokenizedStr;

    size_t loc, prevLoc = 0;
    while( (int)(loc = testStr.find_first_of("\n", prevLoc) ) > 0) {
        string subStr = testStr.substr(prevLoc, loc-1);        // -1 to skip the \n                                                                                                     
        cout << "SUBSTR: '" << subStr << "'" << endl << endl;
        tokenizedStr.push_back( subStr );
        prevLoc = loc+1;
    } // while                                                                                                                                                                        

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If find_X() fails to find the appropriate character then it returns std::string::npos you should explicitly test for this (rather than > 0) as some big string will break.

Comment: You can write this a lot more simply by calling std::getline() on a stringstream.

Comment: @LokiAstari when would this fail?  When would find_X() return a negative number besides npos?

Comment: Yes. size_t is unsigned value. Thus any length that sets the last bit when converted to int(assuming 1 or 2's compliment) will produce a negative value. If the string is very very very long. But best not to make assumptions as this may not hold on all systems (ie some system may have 16 bit size_t). So test for what the documentation explicitly says will be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of `substr` is a size, not a location.  Instead of calling it like this:

```
testStr.substr(prevLoc, loc-1);
```

Try this:

```
testStr.substr(prevLoc, loc-prevLoc);
```

Once you fix that, the next problem you will run into is that you are not printing the last substring, because you are stopping once you don't find the newline.  So from the point of the last newline to the end of the string doesn't get stored.